# Spring Data Elasticsearch 4 - Override Object Mapper?

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

Previously in version 3 of Spring Data Elasticsearch, the Jackson mapper was used by default, but could be overridden to use the Metamodel object mapper, as documented here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/3.2.0.RC1/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping.meta-model

I understand the Jackson mapper has been removed in version 4 and replaced with the Metamodel object mapper, as documented here:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.mapping

But it appears the ability to override the object mapper was removed as well. Is there indeed no way to configure the Elasticsearch global object mapper to use Jackson (or any other mapper) again? It seems like a shame to lose the flexibility that option provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The MappingConverter is not only used and needed for converting an entity to and from JSON, but also for converting and mapping fieldnames, dateformats and other stuff for example when `CriteriaQuery`s are created  or when search resukts like highlights are processed. There are man places in Spring Data Elasticsearch where the mapping information for an entity is needed and Jackson cannot be used there.

So in versions before 4.0 it was necessary to customize Jackson with jackson-annotations on the entity and the other stuff with different annotations, this has been consolidated.

What functionality do you need that the MappingConverter (implementation of the meta model mapper) does not offer in combination with custom converters?

**Edit 05.12.2020**:

valid point from the comments: It should be possible to define a FieldNamingStrategy for an entity. I created [an issue for that](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-993).

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! The key functionality that Jackson provided was defining the Property Naming Strategy. In my use case, our API is snake case but POJOs are camel case, and Jackson let us easily map between the formats without having to specify the name of every single field in an annotation.

Comment: So you can use Jackson to convert POJOs to your API representation, how does this relate to how Spring Data Elasticsearch maps the data?

Comment: My apologies I should have explained more, our purpose for using Elasticsearch at all is for API filtering. We are transforming the parameter string into a match query to retrieve the results from ES. Since all our documents are indexed with camel case fields, we aren't able to use our API field names when passing in the filter parameter. If we could configure ES to index our documents with the API representation as well, it would work together seamlessly. Otherwise we are looking at having to add @Field annotations to hundreds of fields across all our POJOs so it will match the API names.

Comment: I created an issue to add FieldNamingStrategy to Spring Data Elasticsearch

Comment: Excellent thank you! I appreciate the responses and look forward to the FieldNamingStrategy support!

Comment: Another way it differs is in the way it serializes custom collection.